# Rest or java API to get a user's security schemes or security levels

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

Is there any REST API or Java API through which I can get a user's security schemes or security levels? I want to know to what security level or security scheme the user is added.